# Sling Mock is not allowing to get ResourceResolverFactory

Tags: mocking, jcr, sling

Given code:

```
public class TestExample {
  @Rule
  SlingContext slingContext = new SlingContext(ResourceResolverType.JCR_MOCK);


  @Test
  public void test() {
    ResourceResolverFactory rrf = slingContext.getService(ResourceResolverFactory.class);
  }
}
```

Gives me:

```
org.apache.sling.resourceresolver.impl.ResourceResolverFactoryActivator$1 cannot be cast to org.apache.sling.api.resource.ResourceResolverFactory
java.lang.ClassCastException
    at example(ExampleTest.java:21)
```

Do I have to use `slingContext.resourceResolver()` method? It is not flexible as I want, because of existing only `ResourceResolver` instance at once (and it is closed on `tearDown` which my class is doing by itself). Can I avoid this problem somehow?

Answer (score 0):

The following code works for me

```
public class RRFTest {

    @Rule
    public final SlingContext slingContext = new SlingContext(ResourceResolverType.JCR_MOCK);

    @Test
    public void readRootWithRRF() throws LoginException {
        ResourceResolverFactory rrf = slingContext.getService(ResourceResolverFactory.class);
        ResourceResolver resolver = rrf.getAdministrativeResourceResolver(null);

        Resource resource = resolver.getResource("/");

        Assert.assertNotNull(resource);
    }
}
```

using the following dependencies

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.sling</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.apache.sling.testing.osgi-mock</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.sling</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.apache.sling.testing.jcr-mock</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.6</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.sling</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.apache.sling.testing.sling-mock</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

What versions of Sling mocks are you using?